# Can't get JSON data from jQuery AJAX API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

My API URL returns the following JSON:

```
[{"_id":{"$id":"529c759d361ae724088b4568"},"name":"1877","soundcloud_url":"","genres":["rock","electro"]}]
```

Here is my jQuery AJAX call:

```
$.ajax({
 url: gigniteAPI,
 dataType: "jsonp",
 complete: function (data) {

     var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
     alert(ParsedObject);

     }
  });
```

In chrome I can see the script call and that the data that is sent back. However when I JSON.stringify the result all I get is:

```
{"readyState":4,"status":200,"statusText":"success"}
```

Why is it not outputting my API data?

Is it to do with the square brackets in my response?

UPDATE:

Perhaps someone can get this jsfiddle to output the 'name' key from the json response? http://jsfiddle.net/T85eB/

Comment: You API is returning JSON, not JSONP.

Comment: @Barmar What dataType should I use? dataType: json is for domain-same origin requests.

Comment: If it's a different domain, you need to fix the server so it returns JSONP instead of JSON.

Comment: JSONP response looks like `callbackname(JSON);`

Comment: Surely you'd want to use JSON.parse() instead of JSON.stringify() on the incoming data?

Comment: @Barmar unfortunately I don't have control over the API server.

Comment: Then you need to use a local proxy on your server to get around the cross-domain issue.

Comment: @fpsColton jQuery automatically parses it when you specify the JSON or JSONP `dataType`.

Answer (score 3):

The `complete` function receives the XHR object as a response.  I believe you should be using .done(function...) to get the data:

This is taken from here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: gigniteAPI,
    dataType: "jsonp")
})
.done(function (data) {

     var ParsedObject = JSON.stringify(data);
     alert(ParsedObject);

     }
  })
```

;

Comment: Why `.done()`, why not use the `success` property of `$.ajax`? Also, I need to double check if `.done()` would even work there - is it going to pick up `data` at all.

Comment: Well, `done(function(data) { /*...*/}) does work, but I still think `success` is more appropriate.

Comment: These do not seem to work. Here is a jsfiddle to test them out http://jsfiddle.net/T85eB/

Comment: @Vld I think the direction jQuery is moving is towards methods like `.done` rather than options like `success:`.